# Mysqlimport from pipe

Tags: mysql, linux, mysqlimport

I'm trying to figure out how to pipe output into mysqlimport without any luck.  I have a huge file (~250 GB) that I want to pipe to mysqlimport after processing it.  I don't want to create an intermediate file/table.  I'm imagining something like this:

cat genome.mpileup | nawk 'sub("^...","")' | mysqlimport -uuser -ppassword Database

But obviously this isn't working.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: "Isn't working" means what, exactly?

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't look like mysqlimport can read from STDIN but you can perhaps experiment with a [named pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo). Something like this (untested)

```
mkfifo bigfile
mysqlimport -uuser -ppassword Database bigfile &
cat genome | nawk > bigfile
```

Or you can use [an extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) to bash to run commands instead of files

```
mysqlimport -uuser -ppassword Database <(cat genome | nawk)
```

Comment: bash extension won't work since it expects the filename to be = to the table name.  The first approach file not found/can't get stat of file error.

Comment: has anyone been successful using a named pipe? It does not seem to work for me.

Comment: The first version works fine and helped me find out how I could get progress with mysqlimport, simply `pv genome > bigfile` in this case. Thanks! The second version will not work, because MySQL requires a filename.