# Tracking process of mysqlimport command

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, named-pipes, mysqlimport

I have a mysqlimport command which I am running through Python subprocess. The task it is performing is to upload a csv file to a DB table. I would like to track the progress of the running command.

I have looked upon the pipe_viewer module of ubuntu but got no clue to solve the problem.

```py
pro = Popen(["mysqlimport", "--ignore-lines=1", "--fields-terminated-by=\',\'", "--local", "-u", root, "-ppassword", database_name, "home/root/Desktop/file.csv"], stdout=PIPE)
```

Here is the terminal command:

```
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=',' --local -u root -ppassword database_name home/root/Desktop/file.csv
```

The output of the command is received at the finish of import:

database_name.file: Records: 590540  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 92362478

Now, there is no output related to progress which is to be tracked.

**EDIT :** Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15842216/12045568) for reference and help with the proper syntax.

Comment: You cannot since the load data infile statement does not provide any progress update and the utility is basically a wrap around this statement.

Comment: Hey @Shadow, thanks for the response. I would like to know if it is possible to solve the problem using [pipe_viewer](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml).

Comment: Well, try it out and you will see.